# Can malware run itself after user enters sudo mode?

Tags: sudo

As far as I know malware is very uncommon in Linux systems, because majority of important commands require root access. So my question is, can malware just wait until I enter `sudo` mode (for example by doing `sudo apt-get update`) and then execute malicious commands in that timeframe while `sudo` mode is active, without user's knowledge?

Comment: Once malware is running on your computer, it's no longer your computer, it's the attacker's computer. (Exception: if the attacker is stupid, an antivirus might be able to remove the malware. But you can't rely on the attacker being stupid. Antivirus software only keeps stupid attackers out, which makes it pretty much useless.)

Comment: So define 'running' on my computer. Let's say I accidentally download malware, but it cannot do anything because it does not have root access, is it right? That's the main reason why linux systems are mostly absent of malware as far as I understand.

Comment: If you download malware and don't execute it, there's no problem. If you execute malware on your account, then obviously it can do everything you can do: log everything you type, use all the network access that you have, etc. [Root access isn't that useful for most malware](http://xkcd.com/1200/); mainly, root access allows malware to hide its track a lot better.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

No. Sudo is not a mode of the computer. Sudo executes the specified command with root privilege. Malware can only get in if you use sudo to execute the malware or if the apt-get executable has been compromised. Of course apt-get is protected and requires root privilege to modify.

Notice that if you bring up two terminals and enter `sudo su` to operate in the shell as root, commands entered in the other window do not have privilege.

Comment: Nonsense. If the user account is infected by malware, that malware can piggyback on a sudo call so that what `sudo` is instructed to execute is not what the user instructed. The malware can also log the credentials passed to `sudo` so that afterwards it can call `sudo` surreptitiously — not that it would need to, since having had root access once is enough to plant malware running as root. @user1880405

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

If your user account is compromised (as in someone/something else can run arbitrary commands in your name), then they can for instance modify your `~/.bashrc` and add something like:

```
alias sudo='sudo sh -c '\''install-my-backdoor; exec "$@"'\'' sh'
```

so that when you run `sudo apt-get update`, it actually runs `sudo sh -c 'install-my-backdoor; exec "$@"' sh apt-get update`, that is run `install-my-backdoor` as root and then `apt-get update`.

They can also monitor what you type and get your password (which is even worse).

Comment: Well I am not talking about compromised user account, just if attacker/malware can run root commands while user is in sudo more. But thanks for this info.

Comment: @user1880405, if the attacker can run arbitrary commands _as you_, then they can get superuser privilege the next time you run `sudo` (or if you've run `sudo` recently from any terminal that is still active, they can run `sudo` again without needing your password)

Comment: Makes sense, but then I wonder is it easy for an attacker to run commands as me?

Comment: @user1880405, generally not, they need to exploit bugs, misconfiguration, or your trust for that. But your question as worded, suggests that you had already executed the malware code.

Comment: But then again even if I executed it without sudo, it most likely won't do much harm? But like you said, I guess there are many factors to consider.

Comment: @user1880405. If you executed it without `sudo`, it's still code that executed as you and could do anything as far as you know including install a backdoor to receive more malicious code to run and add that `sudo` wrapper to your .bashrc. If your account was compromised, then you can consider the machine compromised (especially if you're a sudoer).

Comment: Thanks for good info, sir, didn't know about that `alias sudo` thing before :)